# Consistent tagging across multiple projects in separate Git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, maven-2, build-process, release-management

I'm working on a product which relies on several different projects each hosted in its own Git repository.  When a release is made, it would be ideal for us to consistently tag every project that is involved in building the product - this includes the core code, libraries and build tools.  Is there an obvious and sensible way to tag all projects at once?

(It may be a distraction, or might be worth noting that each project is using Maven; perhaps there are plugins for managing this.  If so, I've not found any.)

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but you could make a git "super project" which includes all the others as sub modules.  Apply your tag to the super project and I believe it will record the current commit each of the sub modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit broad (at least for me) in its current state but the [Maven Release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) might help to do things in a consistent way. Pay a special attention to the [Prepare a Release](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) example.

Comment: @Ali This plugin captures and automates a lot of good practices and *is* extremely useful. Check it out.

Comment: Using maven-release-plugin seems to be a much better approach than my idea of tagging everything manually - it makes sure that non-SNAPSHOT releases are consistently tagged in the repository.  Thanks, Pascal.